# DirectShow: meaning of pCapsFlags in GetRange method of IAMCameraControl and IAMVideoProcAmp

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow

I'm wondering what the parameter `pCapsFlags` of DirectShow's [`IAMCameraControl::GetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IAMVideoProcAmp::GetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376035(v=vs.85).aspx) mean. MSDN says the following

> Receives a member of the `CameraControlFlags` enumeration, indicating
>   whether the property is controlled automatically or manually.

however, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me since this is what the Get methods do. Also, `GetRange` gives me values of 1, 2 and 3 for most properties, so I was assuming that the return value here would be possible flags, thus a combination of `CameraControl_Flags_Auto` (0x0001) and `CameraControl_Flags_Manual` (0x0002).

While this would be handy, for some properties the returned value is 0, which doesn't support my assumption.

Can anybody tell me what the true meaning is?

Comment: The meaning is straightforward: property can be controlled manually and/or automatically (by hardware). Zero value meaning is that there is no control (not so much different from "property not supported").

Comment: Okay, what I thought would mean "property not supported" would be a `HRESULT` return value other than `S_OK`. What sense does it make to specify minimum, maximum, steppingDelta and default values (via `GetRange`) when the property is not supported in the first place? I'd assume, non-supported properties would simple be not "gettable"? After all there are such properties, and I thought these are the ones not supported.

Comment: A buggy driver can pass that - I saw cases like this.

Comment: Actually, no, using a _MS LifeCam Studio_ I'm able to set both values and flags (in this case it's about `VideoProcAmp_Brightness`) without Set returning an error. I'm not sure about the flags, but I can definitely tell that the image is changing when I modify the value.

Comment: I don't think you get zero in `pCapsFlags` with MS LifeCam Studio camera.

Comment: Well, in fact, I do.

Comment: This is possible, however highly unexpected. Microsoft LifeCam HD-5001, Microsoft LifeCam VX-1000, Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM) - all for brightness report 2, not zero. You can check it with [`DirectShowCaptureCapabilities`](http://alax.info/blog/1531) if you want.

Comment: My LifeCam HD-5001 also reports zeros in both sets of flags as well. DirectShowCaptureCapabilities confirms this (see below). Despite the zero flags, the camera reacts normally to changes in the brightness property. Here is the (abbreviated output) from DirectShowCaptureCapabilities: 

## Device: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-5001
### IAMVideoProcAmp

VideoProcAmp_Brightness: 169, flags 0x00, 30..255, step 1, default 133, cap flags 0x00

Comment: Yeah, same here, driver version 4.25.531.0: _VideoProcAmp_Brightness: 143, flags 0x00, 30..255, step 1, default 133, cap flags 0x00_ Well, at least I know it is not standard behaviour and my interpretation of the flags are correct.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one who sees this behavior. We are seeing it via the IAMVideoProcAmp interface, but note the strong similarity between that and the IAMCameraControl interface. The MSDN doc on the latter actually says, albeit obliquely, that a `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE` flag is a possibility and that this "flag's" bit-mask is, indeed, 0x0000L. Never heard of a no-flag flag before, but there it is. Not sure what it means, but have a look yourself and let me know what you think: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318251

Comment: BTW, my driver is version 4.25.532.0.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty weird, I agree. Only thing to do is check if 'KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_RELATIVE' bit is set and assume relative otherwise. Still, a value of 0x00 for an actually supported property seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Agreed. Looking at Ksmedia.h, it appears that the `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE` "flag" is really just the absence of the `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_FLAGS_RELATIVE` flag. Your camera either takes relative values, or it doesn't (and if it doesn't, it necessarily takes absolute values). Calling this a flag seems like a really bad decision. Moreover, this may have nothing to do with why our LifeCams behave as they do. Most likely, it's just the bug it appears to be.

Comment: For even more wacky fun with your LifeCam 5001, create a simple graph to render its output in graphedt.exe or GraphEditPlus, run the graph, open the cam's property sheet, set the brightness to 255 and then set the zoom to 5 or more. The brightness will suddenly drop to its lowest level, although the property value won't change on the sheet. Not sure, but I think it goes to zero. Be sure to set to something in the legal 30-255 range before you exit, or things go badly the next time you try to add the cam to a graph. Something goes awry and Windows unloads the driver. This is one cranky gadget.